# find the principal value of $\log(i^e) ?$

Tags: complex-analysis

how  to  find the principal value  of $\log(i^e) ?$

My attempts :

$\log \left(e^{{i^e}.\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)$

Now  I am not able to proceed further, please help me

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**$$\log(i^e)=\log(e^{e\log(i)})=e\log(i)$$ Then use the principal branch of $\log$ to evaluate $\log(i)$. The principal branch is that $$\log(z)=\log|z|+i\arg(z)$$

Comment: thanks john Doe

Answer (score 0):

The principal logarithm ( sometimes capital letters are used to indicate you are working with principal values) of $z$ is
$$
\text{Log}\,z=\log|z|+i\, \text{Arg}\,z
$$
where $\text{Arg}\,z$ is the principal argument
and there will be a convention regarding $\text{Arg}\,z$ e.g.
$$
-\pi \lt \text{Arg}\,z \le \pi
$$
You can simplify a little to get
$$
e\, \text{Log}\, i
$$

Then you need to work out $\log|i|$ and $\text{Arg}\, i$.